# Sort Cyrillic strings before Latin in python

Tags: python, sorting, unicode, collation

In my database, I have records in both Cyrillic and Latin characters. By default, they are listed alphabetically with Latin records first:

> abc... bcd... cde... абв...

I would like to put the Cyrillic to the first place:

> абв... abc... bcd... cde...

What I have tried so far:

1. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360878/how-to-sort-latin-after-local-language-in-python-3). It is not so great because it only sorts by the
   first word, and I can have both Cyrillic and Latin words in the same
   string (or even mixed characters in the same word).
2. Writing my own lists with Cyrillic and Latin alphabets. It works but
       is not great at all. I cannot take into account all possible letters
       in the two alphabets, including those with diacritics and write them
       down.

I have also been looking into PyICU but don't see how I can put it to use.

My guess is that I should use some custom collation here. The question is how this can be done in practice.

Comment: So, what is the exact order you want to achieve? "I would like to put the Cyrillic to the first place" - should any string which contains Cyrillic character come before all-Latin strings?

Comment: @ZaurNasibov Not really. I want that every Cyrillic character come before a Latin character. For example, 'waюnt' (with one Cyrillic character) should come before 'wannt': the third letter differs in the two words, and the Cyrillic comes before the Latin. But if we have 'wqюнт' and 'wannt', here 'wannt' should come first, as we compare the second letter, and 'a' precedes 'q' in the Latin alphabet.

Comment: You could use a `key` function in `sorted` or `list.sort` that pre-pends eg a `0` if the first string character is Cyrillic, 1 if not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to take into account every character, not the first one only.

Comment: @Edmond what do you expect in case of 'zжz', 'zzв' ?  And also in 'zвz', 'zzж'?

Comment: Then the `key` lambda will have some extra work to do. Worst case, you could prepend every character. The key point is that sorting depends entirely on the `key` lambda. The key result doesn't have to look anything like the input as long as it produces the desired sort order. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243831/unicode-block-of-a-character-in-python) shows how to detect the Unicode block of a character. Or you could just check the numeric value [against the block's range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_(Unicode_block))

Comment: @Alex We compare every letter in an iteration. So, 1st letter: 'z' and 'z': no difference; second letter: 'ж' and 'z': we have a Cyrillic and a Latin letter, so the Cyrillic precedes. We finish our iteration, and the sorting is: zжz... zzв.

Comment: @Edmond ok, got it

Comment: @snakecharmerb PostgreSQL. But the sorting actually occurs with the strings after they have been retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use the [`transliterate` module](https://pypi.org/project/transliterate/) or maybe [`cytranslit`](https://pypi.org/project/cyrtranslit/) and use a sort key that transliterates everything to the desired alphabet:

```py
import transliterate

items = ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'абв']

print(sorted(items, key=lambda x: transliterate.translit(x, 'ru')))
```

The output is the desired

```
['абв', 'abc', 'bcd', 'cde']
```

Comment: The Russian alphabet is not what I want. I need the Cyrillic alphabet, not Russian. To put it more clearly, all characters of Cyrillic-based languages.

Comment: Nice use of transliterate module, had no idea about it :)

Comment: It only works because all Latin strings in the example were transliterated to Russian strings which sort higher than 'абв'. If the first string in the example is 'aba', not 'abc', then it doesn't work. It will also completely mess up sorting of pure Latin strings, for example, sorted('ccc', 'ddd') will give you ('ddd', 'ccc')

Comment: @Edmond I added a reference to `cytranslit` too. It contains mapping tables you might be able to use. https://github.com/opendatakosovo/cyrillic-transliteration/blob/master/cyrtranslit/mapping.py

Comment: OK, thanks for your suggestion and correction, but this definitely does not fit what I am asking for.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this is not a trivial thing. I'd say that a collation is indeed required.

So, say a key function would convert a string to a tuple of codepoints, where all non-Cyrillic code points would be shifted by 100000):

```
import unicodedata

def key(s):
    SHIFT = 100000
    return tuple(
        ord(c) if is_cyrillic(c) else ord(c) + SHIFT
        for c in s
    )

def is_cyrillic(c):
    return unicodedata.name(c).startswith('CYRILLIC')        


>>> sorted(('wannt', 'waюnnt'), key=key)
Out[34]: ['waюnnt', 'wannt']
```

`is_cyrillic` can be optimized by using a preliminary table or caching the Cyrillic characters from the database strings.

Comment: An optimization could be to check the character's codepoint against the Cyrillic range (U+0400-U+04FF).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, good point! This would be much faster. For full range, all the extensions and supplements have to be checked too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate a key by prepending every character with 1 if it's a Latin character and with 0 otherwise:

```
sorted(items, key = lambda item : ['1' + x if x < '\x7f' else '0' + x for x in item])
```

Comment: `á` is a latin letter too. Test for Cyrillic, as that is contained in just a few Unicode subranges. Nice idea, still.

Answer (score 0):

Very dirty but working solution for sorting according the first character. It also eliminates difference in register of letters.

```
ls = ['32', '24', 'xyz', 'WYZ', 'abc', 'абв', 'КЛМ', 'эюя', 'еёж', 'ёжз', '', '_']

def sort_rule(st):
    st = st.lower()
    ch = st[0] if st else ''       
    if ch >= 'а' and ch <= 'я':
        st = '1' + st
    elif ch == 'ё':
        st = '1е' + st
    elif ch >= 'a' and ch <= 'z':
        st = '2' + st
    else:
        st = '3' + st
    return st

sorted(ls, key=sort_rule)

> ['абв', 'еёж', 'ёжз', 'КЛМ', 'эюя', 'abc', 'WYZ', 'xyz', '', '24', '32', '_']
```

For comparison, default sorting gives the next result:

```
sorted(ls)

> ['', '24', '32', 'WYZ', '_', 'abc', 'xyz', 'КЛМ', 'абв', 'еёж', 'эюя', 'ёжз']
```

Comment: The question is about Cyrillic, not Russian. This answers covers the Russian langauge only.

Answer (score 0):

This in an old question, with four answers, but I feel the following answer is more appropriate.

If you have both icu4c and PyICU installed, there is a fairly simple solution. ICU uses the CLDR Collation Algorithm, a tailoring of the Unicode Collation Algorithm.

Since you want a language insensitive sort with all Cyrillic characters sorted first, the simplest approach is to tailor the CLDR root collation. All tailorings of ICU collations are tailorings of the root collation, and you provide the minimum changes required.

In this scenario, you just need a reorder directive:

```py
from icu import RuleBasedCollator
items = ['cde', 'abc', 'bcd', 'абв']
rules = "[reorder Cyrl]"
collator = RuleBasedCollator(rules)
sorted(items, key=collator.getSortKey)
# ['абв', 'abc', 'bcd', 'cde']
```

But the above rules do exactly what the [Russian collation rules](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/main/icu4c/source/data/coll/ru.txt) do, reordering Cyrillic based on the root collation.

```py
from icu import Locale, Collator
items = ['cde', 'abc', 'bcd', 'абв']
collator = Collator.createInstance(Locale("ru"))
print(sorted(items, key=collator.getSortKey))
```